# Padding mechanism used in onion routing

Tags: padding, onion-routing

I would like to get a correct understanding of the padding mechanism used in onion routing. The following is taken from the original paper of onion routing[https://www.onion-router.net/Publications/IH-1996.pdf].

> Notice that at each hop the onion shrinks as a layer is peeled off. To
> avoid compromised nodes inferring route information from this
> monotonically diminishing size, a random bit string the size of the
> peeled offlayer is appended to the end of the payload before
> forwarding. No proxy except the last will know how much of the payload he receives is
> such padding because he won't know where he is in the chain. He simply `decrypts' the
> padding along with the rest of the onion

To make my question concrete, let's assume the chain is of length 3 consisting of $X$, $Y$, $Z$, where $Z$ is the last node in the chain. Let's also assume the chain keys have already been established. From my understanding, if the source wants to send $M$ to a destination using this chain, it encrypts $M$ as follows:

$$
O_Z = \left[\_,C_Z = E.K_{FZ}(M), T_Z=\text{MAC}.K'_{FZ}(C_Z)\right] \\
O_Y = \left[Z, C_Y = E.K_{FY}(O_Z), T_Z=\text{MAC}.K'_{FY}(C_Y)\right] \\
O_X = \left[Y, C_X = E.K_{FX}(O_Y), T_Z=\text{MAC}.K'_{FX}(C_X)\right] 
$$
assuming authenticated encryption is used to encrypt the payload.

If $X$ receives $O_X$ from the sender, $X$ peals of the outer layer and sends $O_Y$ to $Y$ and so on. It is clear that the size of onion will shrink if only the decrypted onion is forwarded.

If X adds random padding to $O_Y$ before sending it to $Y$, how can $Y$ know the size of the padding? If $Y$ can somehow determine the size of the padding, I think $Y$ can know where he is in the chain which contradicts what is argued in the original paper. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that onion routing has improved _considerably_ since the original paper, and issues unforeseen by the authors are now considered obvious.